# casperjs clicklabel

Tags: javascript, xpath, casperjs

The CasperJS `clicklabel` allows us to click on DOM element of a kind of tag and inner text.

What if the inner text is wrapped by 2 or more levels? Will it work? For example:

```
<a href='xxxxxx'><span>my inner text</span></a>
```

I have tried the below, both seem doesn't work.

```
clicklabel('my inner text','a')
clicklabel('my inner text','a/span')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
clicklabel('my inner text','a span')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
this.click('a > span');
```

This will perform a click event on the first span element inside the 'a' tag.

Answer (score 1):

According to the casperjs docs [clickLabel's](http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.clickLabel) second parameter is the node name, in your case this is 'span', it doesn't take a selector.  You might want to use click instead and use XPath instead of a css selector.

```
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
this.click(x('//span[text()="my inner text"]'));
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are pretty sure that the href attribute is constant just use click with something like : `click("a[href='xxxxx']");`

else you can try `clickLabel('my inner text','span')`

if both fail, check that you are not in a page which uses frames, if that's your case, check http://casperjs.org/api.html#casper.withFrame for how to handle it.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use :

`clickLabel('my inner text','span');`

If its not working try waiting for 5 seconds or more after the click , like :

```
this.wait(5000, function() {
        this.echo("I've waited for 5 seconds.");
    });
```

waiting for 5 seconds did the trick,as i also faced the same issue.